# Post parameters value to multiple file during ajax requesnt

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am passing `myid` to url.php page and also loading this by ajax request. 
At same moment I want to post `myid` to some other file other then url.php. Like x.php,y.php.

```
FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email,name', function(mydata) {
           var email=mydata.email;
              var json = JSON.stringify(mydata.movies.data);
              var a = JSON.parse(json);
              $.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a, name: name, email: email, myid:myid}, function(data) 
                     {
                       $.ajax({
                         url:'url.php'
                         ,async:     true
                         ,type : 'POST'
                         ,cache:     false
                         ,data : 'myid=' + myid   //Here I post myid to url.php. How can I post it to other files like x.php , y.php on same moment?
                         ,dataType:  'html'
                         ,success:   function(data){
                           $('body').html(data);
                           FB.XFBML.parse();
                         }
                       }
                             );

                     }
                    );
```

Bottom line is I want to use current `user_id` e.i. `myid` on various page after user performs login action.

**UPDATE**

I post variables from `index.php` to `url.php`. 
inside index.php:
     $.ajax({
                                 url:'url.php'
                                 ,async:     true
                                 ,type : 'POST'
                                 ,cache:     false
                                 ,data : 'myid=' + myid   //Here I post myid to url.php. How can I post it to other files like x.php , y.php on same moment?
                                 ,dataType:  'html'
                                 ,success:   function(data){}

In url.php I will recv:

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['myid'];
?>
```

Now in `url.php` suppose I alsi have:

```
<script>
function funInclude()
{
  include "data1.php";
  include "data2.php";
}
</srcipt>
```

So data1.php and daa2.php both of them will recv `myid` right?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Put two more ajax calls inside the success callback of the first ajax call
2. In the `url.php` page, simply include the other two php pages and they'll also get the variable data

If you choose option 2, I suggest you do the include inside a function call to partially separate those pages' variables from the calling page

**Edit: To explain option #2 and putting it in a function call:**

In PHP, when you include a file, you are not just "calling" the other page, but including the code as though it were part of the currently running page. They will be compiled together as one page. This can cause unforeseen problems as `page 1`, which includes `page 2`, might have a variable of the same name as `page 2` and `page 2` could change that variable. This would lead to an unexpected variable value on `page 1`.

To account for this, PHP allows you to (partially) restrict the scope of an include page and its variables by calling the include inside a function.

**Example of "calling.php"**

```
<?php
//This included page's variables are accessible as though they were in this "calling.php" page
include "included.php";

function restrictScope()
{
    //This page's variables/changes are only accessible inside this function
    include "included2.php";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

**EDIT: Complete working example**

**This is the base page: include.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="include.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="myid" value="3" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" )
{
    //Let's call included.php
    passOff();

    //Now let's check it actually did it
    $savedId = ( file_exists( "myid.txt" ) ) ? file_get_contents( "myid.txt" ) : "null";

    echo "MyId: " . $savedId;
}

function passOff()
{
    include "included.php";
}
?>
```

**This is the included page: included.php**

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" )
{
    //Create and write the "myid"
    file_put_contents( "myid.txt", $_POST[ "myid" ] );
}
?>
```

**IMPORTANT: For my example to work, you must have write permissions in your web folder. But even if the writing of the file fails, the included page still gets the posted variables.**

Comment: Thanks, the reason for 2nd I could not understand. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: @Karimkhan Added an explanation

Comment: thanks. If we include in function suppose. then variable posted to calling.php will also be received by other included file inside url.

Comment: @Karimkhan I don't know what you're saying. Can you please try to reword it? Are you saying, if a variable is posted to `calling.php` then that variable is also usable inside the included php file? If so, then yes, that is correct. If you do **not** want that, there is an additional option. Inside the function, just before the `include` statement, you can unset a variable so it won't exist inside the included file: `unset( $someVariable );`

Comment: @Karimkhan I added a complete working example to show it works.